# <!-- [if IE]> to apply margins doesn't apply styles

Tags: html, css

Trying to do an iframe zoom, but the way in which each browser does it gives me issues.  It's the same between everything but IE, where I have to set margins to fit the iframes in their containers.

With IE, it doesn't need these margins, so I want to set the margins to 0.  So I make a condition statement based on the browser but it doesn't want to parse.

```
<style>
    #media .audio {
        margin: -157px -235px -157px -235px;
        -ms-zoom: 0.5;
        -webkit-transform:scale(0.5);
        -moz-transform:scale(0.5);
        -o-transform: scale(0.5);
        text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;

    }

</style>
<!--[if IE]> 
<style>
    #media .audio {
        margin: 0 !important;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

I've checked my syntax over and everything seems to be in order.  Is there an alternate method to do this?  I suppose JS/jQuery, but I'd rather avoid that if I could.

Comment: Why not apply a body class via the conditional tag? Without a fiddle or plunker this is likely not debuggable by us.

Comment: Also it would be good to know, which IE's you're testing.

Comment: It won't work in IE10 or later, as they have deprecated these "tags" and no longer use/support them. You'll have to use javascript, probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<!--[if IE]>` does not work in IE 10+
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/07/06/html5-parsing-in-ie10.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: Opted to do this in PHP, I vardumped the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and got `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; MALNJS)`.  Any clue?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. I would open another question, if you're wondering about the meaning.

Comment: It was just a strpos issue.  Thanks.